# How to hide path name on terminal with mac

Tags: macos, terminal

OS: macOS 10.13.5

I want hide "long" path name on terminal, and I try to edit /etc/.bashrc file, like this:

```
PS1 =' [ ${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\ W] \$ '
```

origin is -> PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
(that's using on Ubuntu's method, Miss Google said to me)

but it is not work, my terminal still show 'long' path name, has possible hide path name on terminal? only visible directory or folder name?

thank for help.

Comment: there's a space between the `PS1` and `=`, delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can input **sudo scutil --set HostName colin** in you terminal, next open one new terminal,you will see name to be **colin**

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]